# jQuery if div has certain text in certain div, hide FIRST div with certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First, this is what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $('div.product-number').text();
  var comparingText = '215365';
  
  if(text == comparingText){
    $('.checkout-spacing').css('display','none'); 
  }
});
```

I want to hide `checkout-spacing` if `.product-number` matches the condition above. But I only want to hide the *first* `.checkout-saving` which comes after the `.product-number` I just checked the condition for.

There will be several `.product-number` and `.checkout-saving` on the page, but never more than one of each inside each div. The `.product-number` will never have the same value twice on the same page, but the `checkout-saving` might (which doesn't really matter, as this is only going be hidden.)

If this is possible, is it possible to also check for several `.product-number` divs, and hide all their `.checkout-saving` child classes? It's not really "child", it comes further down HTML.

Copy of the HTML

```
<div class="mini-product ">
  <div class="mini-product-content">
    <div class="row-flex mini-product-content-wrapper">
      <div class="col any-1-1"><a class="product-image-link" title="PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot" href="blablabla" onclick="Site.Common.trackLink('','', 'event8');">
          <img class="b-lazy product-image b-loaded" src="/image/dv_web_D180001002508551/215365/pny-rtx-3080-10gb-xlr8-gaming-epic-x-rgb-3-fan-3slot.jpg?$digital220x220$" alt="PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot" title="PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot"><noscript><img class="product-image" src="/image/dv_web_D180001002508551/215365/pny-rtx-3080-10gb-xlr8-gaming-epic-x-rgb-3-fan-3slot.jpg?$digital220x220$" alt="PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot" title="" /></noscript>
        </a>
        <div class="product-in-stock--mobile"><span class="items-in-stock">

            <span class="checkout-spacing">På nettlager&nbsp;(100+)</span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
          <span class="store-stock"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-infos any-1-1">
        <div class="product-number sku rsNoDrag">215365</div>
        <div class="row-flex">
          <div class="col-flex S-order-2">

            <div class="product-ratings">
              <div id="BVRRInlineRating-215365" class="product-ratings__stars nd-bv-rating"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="align-center" width="100px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 125 25">
                  <defs>
                    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="100%" id="rateGradient-31-215365">
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#dddddd"></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                  </defs>
                  <use xlink:href="#rating-stars" fill="url(#rateGradient-31-215365)"></use>
                </svg></div>
              <div class="product-ratings__avarage"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-flex S-order-1">
            <a class="product-name" title="PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot" href="blablabla">
              <span class="table any-1-1"><span class="table-cell">PNY RTX 3080 10GB XLR8 Gaming EPIC-X RGB 3-FAN 3Slot</span></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-price">
          <div class="row-price-container">
            <div class="product-price">9&nbsp;365
              <div class="marketplace-seller-name marketplace-seller-name--none"><span class="none">&nbsp;</span></div>
              <div class="amount-of-offers amount-of-offers--none"><span class="none">&nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="energy-label-outer-wrap energy-label--mobile">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span class="sales-point

">Forventet lev. jan 2021</span>
    <div class="row-flex on-hover">
      <div class="col-flex S-order-2 product-btns
two-buttons
"><a href="#" data-href="#215365@store-blablabla;10035@store-MasterRepository" class="el-button normal-btn regular-btn transparent-btn icon before compare-btn animate-icon add-to-compare">
          <span class="el-button-text"><span class="text"><span>Sammenlign</span></span></span>
          <svg class="circular" viewBox="26 26 52 52">
            <circle class="path" cx="52" cy="52" r="25" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"></circle>
          </svg>
        </a>

        <div class="product-price-button price-button--desktop ">


          <div data-href="blablabla" class="button el-button cta add-to-basket no-min-width add-to-basket-ajax normal" title="Legg i handlevogn"><span class="el-button-text">
              <span class="text"><span class="product-price-text">
                  Legg i handlevogn</span></span>
            </span><svg class="circular" viewBox="26 26 52 52">
              <circle class="path" cx="52" cy="52" r="25" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"></circle>
            </svg></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price-button price-button--mobile">
          <a class="button el-button cta normal-btn see-more add-to-basket no-min-width pdp-link" href="blablabla" title="Vis produkt">
            <span class="el-button-text">
              <span class="text">
                <span class="product-price-text">Vis produkt</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-info-wrap">
        <div class="energy-label-outer-wrap energy-label--desktop">
        </div>
        <div class="product-in-stock product-in-stock--desktop"><span class="items-in-stock">

            <span class="checkout-spacing">På nettlager&nbsp;(100+)</span>
            &nbsp;
          </span><br>

          <span class="store-stock"></span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-info-wrap col-flex S-order-1">
        <div class="more-info bulletpoints-info">

          <ul class="specs">
            <li>NVIDIA Turing™ architecture, with 1440MHz core clock and 1710MHz boost clock speeds to help meet the needs of demanding games.</li>
            <li>10GB GDDR6X (320-bit) on-board memory, plus 4352 CUDA processing cores and up to 760GB/sec of memory bandwidth</li>
            <li>PCI Express 4.0 interface - Offers compatibility with a range of systems. Also includes DisplayPort and HDMI outputs for expanded connectivity.</li>
          </ul><span class="additional-info">
            <strong> *Vi har ikke varen på lager, forventet levering i starten av 2021.</strong>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-info-wrap col-flex S-order-3 addictional-info-mobile">

        <span class="additional-info"> *Vi har ikke varen på lager, forventet levering i starten av 2021.</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="empty-container">
      <div class="product-in-stock">
        <span class="items-in-stock "><span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</span><br><span class="store-stock">&nbsp;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the HTML structure; you'll want to include an example of that.

Comment: How do you know which `.checkout-saving` applies to which `.product-number`?

Comment: @MattEllen It's always the first chechout-saving coming after the product-number being checked in the condition. Is this possible?

Comment: @DanielBeck
I just added the HTML. That whole structure, there's many of it on one page. But as I mentioned, it's always the next ```checkout-saving``` which should be hidden, coming after the ```product-number``` we're checking.

Comment: So, you have 2 checkout-spacing spans in your example. You want the second one hidden?

Comment: @MattEllen Oh I just realised that. The first one is probably mobile, second is desktop. Would I be able to hide both? If not, I could have a code for desktop and another one for mobile, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you search through the `.mini-product` for the `.product-number` then when you hit the right number you can search the `.mini-product` again for the `.checkout-spacing` and hide them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const comparingText = '215365';
  $('.mini-product').each((index, mp) =>
  {
    let productNumber = $(mp).find('.product-number').first().text().trim();
    if(productNumber == comparingText)
    {
      $(mp).find('.checkout-spacing').each((csi, cs)=>
      {
        $(cs).css('display', 'none');
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mini-product ">
  <div class="mini-product-content">
    <div class="row-flex mini-product-content-wrapper">
      <div class="col any-1-1">
        <div class="product-in-stock--mobile"><span class="items-in-stock">
            <span class="checkout-spacing">På nettlager&nbsp;(100+)</span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
          <span class="store-stock"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-infos any-1-1">
        <div class="product-number sku rsNoDrag">215365</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-flex on-hover">
      <div class="product-info-wrap">
        <div class="product-in-stock product-in-stock--desktop">
          <span class="items-in-stock">
            <span class="checkout-spacing">På nettlager&nbsp;(100+)</span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have multiple numbers to search for, create an array and use `includes`:

```js
//instead of const comparingText = '215365';
const numbersToCheck = ['215365', '4400', '42'];


//instead of if(productNumber == comparingText)
if(numbersToCheck.includes(productNumber))
{

}
```

Comment: YOU'RE HEAVENSENT. I appreciate you. Thank you so much :D I actually need to check several numbers, and was going to ask you, so thanks for including that in your answer as well! It's so fun learning jQuery. A few months ago I knew nothing.

Comment: Can I ask you a bonus question? If I use the filter to filter products, the jQuery rule disappears, is there any way to have it keep updating/checking for this? Or is that hard?

Comment: Sorry, I think that's out of scope here. I think that is a separate Question of its own.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was. But this is great, thanks!!

Comment: Hi again, one question, I'm getting this error in console: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '207747' is not a valid selector.

Got any idea? I have the first number in numbersToCheck as 207747. It works on the page and it hides the class from this product, but still getting that error.

Comment: somewhere in your code you've got a call to `document.querySelectorAll` and I'm guessing you're passing in the integer `207747`, which isn't valid as a selector. Passing in a plain integer, querySelectorAll would look for an element with the tag 207747. That's not a valid XML or HTML tag name, so it throws the error.

Comment: Is the error supposed to be there? that number is the value of one of the .productNumber we're searching for. It only throws an error for the first number, not the rest of them.

Comment: It's supposed to be there in so far as if you pass a number into querySelectorAll that's the error you'll get. Once the error is thrown then the script stops, so I would guess that's why you're not seeing further errors.